# How to build flutter-debug.apk

Tags: flutter, flutter-apk

I am a beginner and I need some help. I want to generate a flutter apk of debug mode. When I run 'flutter build apk' it only generates the flutter-release.apk file but I want to generate flutter-debug.apk of the latest code.
Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
flutter build apk --debug
```

This should work.
Your app should be in the `build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk` inside your project directory

However for Debugging you should do this through your IDE, for example in visual studio code you just press F5 to debug your app.